# X3DAudio1_7.dll and XAPOFX1_5.dll for gaming in Wine

Tags: wine, xubuntu, games, playonlinux

I'm trying to play XCOM on Wine (using Play on Linux). Unfortunately, this doesn't work.

The debug option in POL outputs this:

```
Running wine-1.5.15 play-XCOM.exe (Working directory : /home/stephen/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/XCOM/drive_c/XCom Enemy Unknown)
p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directoryfixme:shell:SHAutoComplete stub
fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000180
err:module:import_dll Loading library X3DAudio1_7.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\XCom Enemy Unknown\\Binaries\\Win32\\XComGame.exe") failed (error c000007b).
err:module:import_dll Loading library XAPOFX1_5.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\XCom Enemy Unknown\\Binaries\\Win32\\XComGame.exe") failed (error c000007b).
err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Main exe initialization for L"C:\\XCom Enemy Unknown\\Binaries\\Win32\\XComGame.exe" failed, status c0000135
```

This leads me to believe that Wine is missing X3DAudio1_7.dll and XAPOFX1_5.dll. I transfered these files from my Windows install into

```
/home/stephen/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/XCOM/drive_c/windows/system32
```

but it still gives me the same error. What can I do? I tried using Wine overrides but that didn't seem to help either.

I'm running Xubuntu 12.04, XCOM is running in wine 1.5.15

Comment: you can find your file for replacement here http://fix4dll.com/x3daudio1_7_dll , you welcome

Answer (score 3):

I've fixed the error by installing the `dxfullsetup` and `d3dx11` packages.

Comment: Where did you get them from?

Comment: Would be nice if you could describe better how you installed those packages. Did you install them from a source? Did you use winetricks?